# How can I reference an environment variable from Node's .env file?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, dotenv

I have manually defined an environment variable in the shell, and I want to be able to reference this environment variable in a `.env` file in Node. Node's `.env` files don't seem to be able to support calling existing environment variables.

Example `.env`

```
testfilepath=$TEST_PATH/testfile
```

Error:

```
npm start
Error: File does not exist at path: $TEST_PATH/testfile.
```

How can I reference an existing environment variable in a Node .env file?

Answer (score 3):

`dotenv` doesn't support such functionality. You could use [`dotenv-expand`](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv-expand) on top of it to expand existing variables, though:

```
let dotenv = require('dotenv')
let dotenvExpand = require('dotenv-expand')

let myEnv = dotenv.config()
dotenvExpand(myEnv)
```